# Where is least significant byte in C array

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

My question is very simple and trivial, but I haven't found an explicit answer.

if there is C array `char a[2]`, where is least significant byte `a[0]` or `a[1]`

in other word, lower address or higher address ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: That's system dependent. See, for example, [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html)

Comment: It's not at all endian dependent...  It's user defined.

Comment: Since this is a user-defined array, it would depend on what the user defined it to be. If you're talking about the least significant byte in a word (or bigger variable type), that's system dependant (see the link `Nit` provided).

Comment: "*least significant byte of an array*"? "*significant*" in terms of what?

Comment: Do you have a link to that specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the usage, so basically you define it.

For example, if you use `char a[2]` to contain a 2-bit binary number (one of 00, 01, 10, 11), you can define that your LSB bit is at the right side, i.e. at `a[1]`, so the number 01 will be represented by the string "01" (`a[0]` = 0, `a[1]` = 1). This choice seems natural in many cases.

However, you may decide that your needs are suited better by the opposite definition, and you will define that your LSB bit is at the left side, and in that case the number 01 will be represented by the string "10".

Answer (score 5):

The concept of "significance" only makes sense when the unit being talked about (e.g. bit or byte) takes part in *representing a value* made up of more than one such unit. As in indiv's comment, an array of 2 `char` objects has no inherent meaning as a single value. If you choose to use it as such, it's up to you how you interpret the two `char`s and assign numeric meaning to them as a unit.